# Is there a way to split odd and even numbers into 2 lists until both lists have a specific length?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take numbers from input's user and split them into two list, odd or even. I want the code to stop when both lists have a length of 5, and then display the two lists.

I wrote this piece of code that seems to split numbers correctly, but one of the two lists keeps on appending numbers even if has already reached length 5.

```
even_list = []
odd_list = []
while len(even_list) < 5 or len(odd_list) < 5:
    a = int(input("Insert a number: "))
    if a % 2 == 0:
        even_list.append(a)
    else:
        odd_list.append(a)

print(f"Even numbers inserted are: {even_list}")
print(f"Odd numbers inserted are: {odd_list}")
```

I've tried to change the OR to AND but the code doesn't work this way, because it stops running when the first of the two lists is complete and doesn't check the other one. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If `even_list`, say, is already at 5 and another even number is entered, what should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions in the `while` statement only determine if you need to ask for another number.
Since you want to append only if the list doesn't have five elements, you're also going to have to check the length of each list individually before you append:

```
even_list = []
odd_list = []
while len(even_list) < 5 or len(odd_list) < 5:
    a = int(input("Insert a number: "))
    if a % 2 == 0:
        if len(even_list) == 5:
            print("Even list full; input ignored")
        else:
            even_list.append(a)
    else:
        if len(odd_list) == 5:
            print("Odd list full; input ignored")
        else:
            odd_list.append(a)

print(f"Even numbers inserted are: {even_list}")
print(f"Odd numbers inserted are: {odd_list}")
```

This will now print the message `"Even/Odd list full; input ignored"` if the relevant list already contains five elements. As soon as the other list also contains five elements, the `while` loop ends and the contents of the two lists are printed:

```
Insert a number: 1
Insert a number: 2
Insert a number: 3
Insert a number: 4
Insert a number: 5
Insert a number: 2
Insert a number: 2
Insert a number: 2
Insert a number: 2
Even list full; input ignored
Insert a number: 2
Even list full; input ignored
Insert a number: 3
Insert a number: 3
Even numbers inserted are: [2, 4, 2, 2, 2]
Odd numbers inserted are: [1, 3, 5, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for length of list right before appending also, not only as a `while` condition.

```
even_list = []
odd_list = []
while len(even_list) < 5 or len(odd_list) < 5:
    a = int(input("Insert a number: "))
    if a % 2 == 0 and len(even_list) < 5:
        even_list.append(a)
    elif a % 2 != 0 and len(odd_list) < 5:
        odd_list.append(a)

print(f"Even numbers inserted are: {even_list}")
print(f"Odd numbers inserted are: {odd_list}")
```